# How do I append same string variable to a string in a loop

Tags: python, string

I have a list, 
`temp1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`

I want the output as a new list `new_list=['a.b.c.d.e.f']`

I had tried this

```
def combine(temp1, lstart, lend):
    global y,z,x
    for w in temp1[lstart:lend-1]: 
        y=w+"."
        z=w
    for w in temp1[lend-1:lend]:
        z=w

for i in edge_names:
    temp1=(i.split('.'))
    print(temp1)
    right = len(temp1) - 2
    combine(temp1, 0, right)
```

but unable to get the desired result. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this (but there are even better ways as pointed in other answers).

```
s=''  
for i in range(len(temp1)-1):
    s =  s + temp1[i] + '.'
if len(temp1) > 0:
    s =  s + temp1[-1]
newlist = [s]
```

Comment: It's insanity to me that this is the accepted answer. I mean, it works, but the readability of a `join` operation is infinitely better

Comment: @itypewithmyhands.: I apologize first of all for this. And I accept what you said. The other answer contains one of my upvotes. It's better.

Comment: No need to apologise, I was just flabbergasted enough to voice my comment, that's all. OP got what they wanted, and at the end of the day that's the goal here I guess

Comment: @itypewithmyhands.: Yes and no both. I was adding this answer to show that even if you know basics of coding you can realize something. But there are other things that python provides which are useful and efficient. One should know that. (But yes there is always a simple stupid way to get there at first try.)

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to use the .join method

```
new_list = [".".join(temp1)]
```

This will give you the desired output of `new_list = ["a.b.c.d.e.f"]`